# AWS Lambda function can't communicate with EC2 Instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tomcat, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

On AWS, I created a  new lambda function. I added a role to the lambda that has the policy, AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole. I placed the lambda in the same VPC as my EC2 instance and made sure the security group assigned to the lambda and EC2 instance have the same default VPC security group created by AWS which allows all traffic within the vpc. On my EC2 instance, I have a tomcat app running on port 8080. I tried to hit the URL by two methods in my lambda function:

1. Using my load balancer, which has the same assigned security group
2. Hitting the IP address of the EC2 box with port 8080

Both of these options do not work for the lambda function. I tried it on my local computer and it is fine.

Any suggestions?

**Security Group for Inbound**

- Type = All Traffic
- Protocol = All
- Port Range = All
- Source = Group ID of Security Group

Comment: Did you also create the Service role so lamda can assume the role? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-ec-create-iam-role.html

Comment: Yes, I verified this by going to the role, then Trust Relationships, clicked edit and under service, I had the following:

**"Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"**

Comment: It should work as you have described. Could you please Edit your question and add the configuration of the Inbound Security Group on the EC2 instance?

Comment: Added it to the original questions

Answer (score 0):

has the security group 8080 port open to internet?

To connect Lambdas with VPC you can't use the default VPC, you have to create one with a nat gateway.

EDIT: Only if the Lambda fucntion needs to access to internet and VPC.

Comment: It has been opened to the internet. However, why do I need to open it to the internet? I just want it to talk to the EC2 running tomcat that is in the same VPC

Comment: You need a VPC like that http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-gateway.html

Comment: So I have what you listed, but instead of it routing to the NAT gateway it is routing all traffic to my internet gateway. So it is already external facing.

Comment: @AshwinJacob you **do** need a NAT device before a Lambda function inside VPC can access the Internet, but since you are not trying to access the Internet, this answer is not relevant to the specific issue you are trying to resolve.  And, you can, of course, do this with subnets you add to your default VPC.

Comment: It's correct I thought the Lambda function want access to a VPC and Internet. Have you see the CloudWatch logs?

Comment: I checked the logs and it just saying that the lambda function timed out. It only takes a second to get a response back from the server when I test locally

Comment: Try to create a security group for the ec2 and another for the Lambda function. in the first open 8080 port to the second SG. Another idea... I'm not sure Is you can do a traceroute inside of a Lambda, but try it and print the results. Here there is an example https://dnaeon.github.io/traceroute-in-python/